# pyqtgraph : Multiple colors in PyQtGraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, vispy

Can I plot multiple channels with different colors in pyqtgraph with ArrayToQPath?

```
path = pg.arrayToQPath(xdata.flatten(), ydata.flatten(), conn.flatten())
item = QtGui.QGraphicsPathItem(path)
item.setPen(pg.mkPen('w')) 
plt.addItem(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

`QGraphicsPathItem` only supports drawing with a single color, so unfortunately it is necessary to create one item per color. For example, see `examples/MultiPlotSpeedTest.py`.

If this is not fast enough for you, consider using an OpenGL-based vis. library. VisPy has an example of this in `examples/demo/gloo/realtime_signals.py`.

Comment: Hey there Luke, do you know if this is still the case today? Is VisPy providing the pyqtgraph graphics backend?

Comment: No, I"ll update the answer.